# React TypeError. I can't pass from parent to child component useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, setstate

Hello i have parent component which is App , i have 3 child componets Login, TodoForm and TodoList
When im trying to pass hook state to login i got this err - > Login.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: setToken is not a function. I dont have idea why my hooks from App doesnt work in child component(Login)
at Login.js:26:1.

There is a code

```
const Login = ({setIslogin,islogin,setUsername,setToken,token,username}) => {
    const [login, setLogin] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const [userid, setUserid] = useState()
    const navigation = useNavigate()
    


    const sign = () => {
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/login/', { login: login, password: password, islogin: islogin }).then((result) => {
            const user = result.data;
            if (user.islogin == true) {
                setUserid(user.id)
                setToken(user.token)
                window.localStorage.setItem("json token", user.token);
                setUsername(login)
                setIslogin(true)
            }
            else {
                console.log("nie udalo sie zalgoowac")
            }
        })
    }
    if (islogin === true) {
        return (
            <App  userid= {userid}  />
        )
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Header />
                <section class="landing-page">
                    <div class="form-container">
                        <form>
                            <h1>Login</h1>
                            <label>Login</label>
                            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setLogin(e.target.value) }} />
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" onChange={(e) => { setPassword(e.target.value) }} />
                            <button type="button" onClick={sign}>Login</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Login;

And the App component - > 

function App() {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [tasks,setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [islogin,setIslogin] = useState(false);
  const [username,setUsername] =useState('')
  const [userid, setUserid] = useState('')
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const { state } = useLocation();
 
  
 

  if (islogin===false){
    return(<Login setIslogin={setIslogin} setUsername={setUsername} setToken={setToken} token={token} username={username}/>)
  }
  else{
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <li><Link to="/">Home </Link> </li>
          <li><Link to="/login">Login  </Link></li>
        </nav>
        <div class="img-header">
          {/* <img src={require('./logo.png')} /> */}
        </div>

      </header>
      <section class="landing-page">
        <Form setInput={setInput}  input={input} username={username} islogin={islogin} id={userid} tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks} />
        <div class="list-container">

         
          <Todolist  setInput={setInput} input={input} username={username} islogin={islogin} id={userid} tasks={tasks} setTasks={setTasks} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos}/>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: it is due to your condition `if(islogin === false)`, it is not sending the props, because initially it is false.

Comment: i used == and it works <3 thanks bro

Comment: my misstake ,still same error

Comment: can you make a codesandbox for the same?